# SAP B1 Service Layer JavaScript Extensibility SQLQueries

Tags: javascript, sql, service-layer, sapb1

I am triying to use SQLQueries using Service Layer JavaScript Extension to get some info from table OCRD (field DocEntry) beacuse is not expossed in stanard CRUD entities (BusinessPartners). Is there a way to do it? I can retrieve the information by Postman, but I am unable to do it using JavaScript.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Unique key for Business Partners is `CardCode`, and this one is exposed with the BP object, of course.

`DocEntry`, which can be queried from OCRD using SQL, is not exposed within SL's BusinessPartner object.

Comment: Is not exposed by SAP Service Layer, but i can see it in schema database. check it using this query in SAP HANA Studio: SELECT "DocEntry", "CardCode" FROM "<your_schema>"."OCRD";

Comment: You're right, @MarioBotero, did not know that there's an internal property DocEntry in OCRD. You said you could query it via Postman, but not in Javascript? What's the difference between these two requests then?

Comment: I mean I could execute "SQLQueries" via SAP Service Layer using Postman (using an SQL script, similar to the one that I wrote before), but i do not know how to do it using Javascript Extension for SAP Service Layer.

Comment: What I am triying to say is that I can invoke a Standard Entity like "BusinessPartners", "Orders", "PurchaseOrders", UDO, UDT... except SQLQueries.

Answer (score 0):

In `Working with SAP Business One Service Layer` user manual - has this in it:

---

To run the query, there are two ways in the Service Layer: one is to set a payload using POST and the other is to
specify a query parameter using GET.

> By POST

```
POST https://server:50000/b1s/v1/SQLQueries('sql01')/List HTTP/1.1
{
 "ParamList": "docTotal=10.1"
}
```

> By GET

```
GET https://server:50000/b1s/v1/SQLQueries('sql07')/List?docTotal=10.1 HTTP/1.1
```

Comment: Thank you for your response @bkwdesign, but the solution that you propose can be applied using Postman, no in SBO ServiceLayer JavaScript Extensibility.